# Transforming descriptive CSV data to known locations in GIS using Python

Tags: arcpy, cursor, dictionary

I have to transfer CSV data that describes a FROM and TO segment into spatial data. The segment descriptions do not follow any logical convention, but rather describe road junctions, places, or road features (4-lane section). I have decided to use a Python script to iterate through the CSV data, extract the Segment ID, highway #, FROM, and TO fields into a dictionary {ID:segHwy,segFrom,segTo}. This works fine.

The dataset that I am using to then locate these segments is an intersection of 3 datasets in order to capture all possible road names for a match. I need to now figure out how to search through this large dataset and compare it against my dictionary to find matches of all three values in my dictionary.
If both the highway number and the FROM field finds a road match, then I populate a new FROM field in the spatial dataset with the segment ID and 'from'. Same with TO.

In the end, I'm hoping to have a spatial dataset with two populated fields (Seg_From and Seg_To) with the Segment ID from CSV and whether this was a 'from' or 'to' location.
I'm mostly stuck on how to extract key from value and also search through 3 different road name fields in my spatial dataset.
I just have the dictionary so far, am using ArcPy....any help?

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(segData,[segID, segHwy, segFrom, segTo]) as segCursor:
for row in segCursor:
    if row[0] not in segDict:
        segDict[row[0]] = row[1:]
```

Return: {1: ('H35', 'Jct H16', 'end Trestle'), 2: ('H16', 'Nouch Rd', 'Lake Kathlyn Rd W'),....}